# Filtering request to only show 6minutes and below times

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to filter all runs that are <= 6minutes and output the Time, Tier & link to the user profile.

The issue is I get characters mixed up with ints so I need to remove the characters and format the ints for the output to look nice. Then I can move into Tier, then Profile.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rBarb = requests.get("https://eu.diablo3.com/en/rankings/season/17/rift-barbarian").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(rBarb, "html.parser")
pContainer = soup.find(id=("ladders"))
#print(pContainer)
rRiftTime = pContainer.find_all(class_="cell-RiftTime")
print(rRiftTime)
```

That is what I have atm. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `datetime.timedelta` object for easy filtering of results based on time:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from datetime import timedelta

rBarb = requests.get("https://eu.diablo3.com/en/rankings/season/17/rift-barbarian").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(rBarb, "lxml")

# parse the data
data = []
for tr in soup.select('#ladders-table tr')[1:-1]:
    d = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.select('td')] + [tr.select_one('a')['href']]
    g = re.search(r'(\d+)m\s([\d.]+)s', d[3])
    d.append(timedelta(minutes=int(g[1]), seconds=float(g[2]))) # convert string to timedelta object for easy filtering
    data.append(d)

# filter data for any results < 6 minutes
filtered = [d for d in data if d[-1] < timedelta(minutes=6)]

for d in filtered:
    print(d)
```

Prints:

```
['993.', 'Soulnsane', '100', '5m 37.033s', '06-Jun-2019 19:58:49', '/en/profile/Soulnsane-2303/hero/64459758', datetime.timedelta(0, 337, 33000)]
```

Comment: @user9812043 You need to sort the data by the key you want.